# Why does my C++ for loop always execute, despite its condition not being met?

Tags: c++, for-loop, indexing, segmentation-fault

Coming from Java, I'm new to C++.
I am unable to figure out why the following for loop always executes, despite the initial value of `i` exceeding `n - 1`.

```
    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {
        const int n = prices.size();
        int profit = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            cout << "i: " + to_string(i) + ", n - 1: " + to_string(n - 1) + '\n';
            const int diff = prices[i + 1] - prices[i];
            if(diff > 0) { profit += diff; }
        }
        return profit;
    }
```

The output I'm getting (because of the print statement) is:
`i: 0, n - 1: -1`, followed by:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000004 (pc 0x000000382c25 bp 0x7ffd70e65f70 sp 0x7ffd70e65d00 T0)
==32==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==32==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #3 0x7f6ee7f0682f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==32==ABORTING
```

Perhaps I am not seeing something, but can someone tell me why the for loop executes, despite the condition in the for loop being violated?

I am not sure which version of C++ this is. This is coming from LeetCode's online editor.

Comment: The loop will execute as long as `i < n` is true, so unless `n` is `<= 0` it will execute *at least* 1 time.

Comment: The condition of the `for` loop is not "being violated". Free clue: see what the following shows you: `std::cout << (size_t)-1 << std::endl;`, then think about your `n`, and what really happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't have unsigned types but C++ does. If `n == 0` then `n - 1` is mathematically `-1`, but `-1` is not an unsigned value. What happens in this case is that the result *wraps around* and `-1` is actually equal to the largest possible unsigned value. Change your code to this for the expected result

```
for(size_t i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++) {
```

Now there are no negative numbers.

Comment: I think the tricky part is that `n` is signed so `n-1` alone would not be problematic

Comment: Oh yes missed that. Mixing signed and unsigned is a bad idea in general.

Comment: I believe that when being compared to `i`, it is converted to unsigned, and now we have a problem. It's been a little while since I looked up integer conversion rules. It's just a lot easier if the types were the same. `n` should be a `std::size_t`.